# Pushing a Rails app to Heroku - "Precompiling assets failed."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push my Rails app to Heroku and am getting the below error:

```
Counting objects: 151, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (151/151), done.
Writing objects: 100% (151/151), 25.49 MiB | 844.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 151 (delta 94), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path     
vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older         
than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.2). We suggest you upgrade     
to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.3.2
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.6
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using msgpack 1.2.4
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.25
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Using pg 0.21.0
remote:        Using puma 3.12.0
remote:        Using thor 0.20.3
remote:        Using redis 4.1.0
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Using i18n 1.2.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.5
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 9.4.2
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.3.2
remote:        Using sassc 2.0.0
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.1
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.4.0
remote:        Using font-awesome-sass 5.5.0.1
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.1
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.1
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.1
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.1
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.1
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.1
remote:        Using railties 5.2.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using simple_form 4.1.0
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.1
remote:        Using webpacker 3.5.5
remote:        Using sassc-rails 2.0.0
remote:        Using rails 5.2.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now         installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (2.94s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older     than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.2). We suggest you upgrade to         the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 2.0.0.pre.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.5.1
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        yarn install v1.5.1
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed     compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 20.00s.
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.109116 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/Circle-0fced0bef25671945de87c22a37c75605efb7f48d86ed387c97894abc57fc305.png
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.115329 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/architectural-design-architecture-bench-b3126997ea1f82ae64eb45638971e9a9852df31f03b2d80695bceabfedd0d789.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.121854 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/architecture-boy-building-e4a11ead07ae2f196935970b9f6d1617ceff81e1519c02973f7a3a0728b57e44.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.126914 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/architecture-bricks-buildings-52ba2f71d6d3c15c08fb7e526c88f8e4ba486f48490a8047824209fb7ed4beb3.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.131626 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/architecture-building-building-site-377c0ddb71908bb0093d000e36223925eab2e584b6bb583811a47157e15387e1.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.135486 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/asphalt-blur-bricks-9971516befa9aed81640a1be2daed94b2432e1aa8bda5c87e4d4de86981490de.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.163513 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/b&wbricks-e5ad65e07ae90a3aafd45674c36925bc4ce37672a3b7781dec1bf354da53bf15.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.339917 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/build-builder-builders-13272d04c77701847534e350ff582062d78773d79058f9ad13a0e714d1499f93.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.349110 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/portfolio-534dc7c251be1e38e52ab2f31cac69db6955cd4e907c79665627943ab1283231.svg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.349283 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/portfolio-534dc7c251be1e38e52ab2f31cac69db6955cd4e907c79665627943ab1283231.svg.gz
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.354135 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/skyline-contractors-3da17ace5fc02409a2b797a9bf60c5d71710c0da9c7aba834e133e89971b1a27.svg
remote:        I, [2018-12-24T17:14:15.354300 #409]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/public/assets/skyline-contractors-3da17ace5fc02409a2b797a9bf60c5d71710c0da9c7aba834e133e89971b1a27.svg.gz
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (anchorlinks). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_c45535d8c2a0f6b2e090f551394cd52a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to skyline-contactors.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/skyline-contactors.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/skyline-    contactors.git'
```

Before marking this as a duplicate, I have seen other threads with the same issue and have tried the following:

1. Uninstalling & reinstalling bundler (I've previously had bundler version issues),
2. Removing the Gemfile.lock,
3. Tried $rake assets:precompile,
4. Added "config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false" to config/application.rb.

None of these have worked for me, unfortunately.

I recently changed the name of the Heroku file, but I don't think this will have any implications.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.5'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.5.0'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

Apologies in advance if the question has indeed been answered on here before, but I think I have exhausted the existing resources. Please let me know if you see anything that I'm doing completely wrong; any feedback or assistance would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is this part `Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (anchorlinks). To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true)`. This should solve it.

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:harmony => true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rockwell Rice! That worked perfectly!